# Segmentation fault when trying to build image (with Dockerfile) after upgrading to .net 7

Tags: .net, docker, msbuild, apple-m1, qemu

When trying to upgrade a project from .NET 6 to 7, I've stumbled across an issue publishing the project inside the Dockerfile flow.

On my environment the same command works without any issues, but when doing the same through the Dockerfile (`docker build [...]`) if fails and throws a Segmentation fault.

It might be relevant to note that I'm on a Mac with a M1 chip. I'm aware I'm building a linux image on a Mac; passing through the `--platform linux/amd64` argument.

The publish step in the Dockerfile is as follows

```
RUN dotnet publish \
    -c release \
    -r linux-x64 \
    --no-self-contained \
    -p:PublishReadyToRun=true \
    -o published \
    function/function.csproj
```

I'm also using the following base image

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 as builder
```

Before I was using the `bullseye-slim` variant, but swapped for the "regular" one, just in case.

Here's the error output

```
#26 4.225 MSBuild version 17.4.0+18d5aef85 for .NET
#26 6.047 qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
#26 6.438 Segmentation fault
```

I've added the `-v d` to get more verbosity out of the `publish` command but can't see anything useful in it. If anyone has any thoughts, they would be greatly appreciated.

```
#25 4.036 MSBuild version 17.4.0+18d5aef85 for .NET
#25 4.616 Build started 12/06/2022 15:58:06.
#25 4.635      0>Process = "/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet"
#25 4.636        MSBuild executable path = "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/MSBuild.dll"
#25 4.636        Command line arguments = "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/MSBuild.dll -maxcpucount -verbosity:m -restore -target:Publish --property:_IsPublishing=true --property:PublishReadyToRun=true -property:PublishDir=/source/faas/published -property:SelfContained=False -property:_CommandLineDefinedSelfContained=true -property:RuntimeIdentifier=linux-x64 -property:_CommandLineDefinedRuntimeIdentifier=true -property:Configuration=release -verbosity:d function/function.csproj"
#25 4.636        Current directory = "/source/faas"
#25 4.636        MSBuild version = "17.4.0+18d5aef85"
#25 5.120        Resolving SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk'...
#25 5.416        Property 'MSBuildExtensionsPath' with value '/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/' expanded from the environment.
#25 5.449        Property reassignment: $(MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath)="/source/faas/function/obj/" (previous value: "obj\") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Current/Microsoft.Common.props (56,5)
#25 5.474        The "Configuration" property is a global property, and cannot be modified.
#25 5.481        The "Configuration" property is a global property, and cannot be modified.
#25 5.482        Property reassignment: $(AssemblySearchPaths)="{CandidateAssemblyFiles};{HintPathFromItem}" (previous value: "{CandidateAssemblyFiles}") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.props (82,5)
#25 5.482        Property reassignment: $(AssemblySearchPaths)="{CandidateAssemblyFiles};{HintPathFromItem};{TargetFrameworkDirectory}" (previous value: "{CandidateAssemblyFiles};{HintPathFromItem}") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.props (83,5)
#25 5.483        Property reassignment: $(AssemblySearchPaths)="{CandidateAssemblyFiles};{HintPathFromItem};{TargetFrameworkDirectory};{RawFileName}" (previous value: "{CandidateAssemblyFiles};{HintPathFromItem};{TargetFrameworkDirectory}") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.props (84,5)
#25 5.511        Resolving SDK 'Microsoft.NET.SDK.WorkloadAutoImportPropsLocator'...
#25 5.535        Resolving SDK 'Microsoft.DotNet.ILCompiler'...
#25 5.538        Resolving SDK 'Microsoft.NET.ILLink.Tasks'...
#25 5.542        Property reassignment: $(TargetsForTfmSpecificContentInPackage)=";PackTool;_PackProjectToolValidation" (previous value: ";PackTool") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.PackProjectTool.props (15,5)
#25 5.550        Property reassignment: $(OutputType)="Exe" (previous value: "Library") at /source/faas/function/function.csproj (4,5)
#25 5.550        Property reassignment: $(RootNamespace)="OpenFaaS" (previous value: "function") at /source/faas/function/function.csproj (6,5)
#25 5.562        The "Configuration" property is a global property, and cannot be modified.
#25 5.565        Property reassignment: $(PublishProfileImported)="false" (previous value: "true") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportPublishProfile.targets (28,5)
#25 5.638        Property reassignment: $(TargetPlatformVersion)="" (previous value: "0.0") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets (65,5)
#25 5.651        Property reassignment: $(DefaultItemExcludes)=";bin\release//**;obj\release//**" (previous value: ";bin\release//**") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets (226,5)
#25 5.652        Property reassignment: $(IntermediateOutputPath)="obj\release/net7.0/" (previous value: "obj\release/") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets (245,5)
#25 5.652        Property reassignment: $(OutputPath)="bin\release/net7.0/" (previous value: "bin\release/") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets (246,5)
#25 5.655        Resolving SDK 'Microsoft.NET.SDK.WorkloadManifestTargetsLocator'...
#25 5.688        The "SelfContained" property is a global property, and cannot be modified.
#25 5.688        The "SelfContained" property is a global property, and cannot be modified.
#25 5.691        Property reassignment: $(IntermediateOutputPath)="obj\release/net7.0/linux-x64/" (previous value: "obj\release/net7.0/") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets (279,5)
#25 5.691        Property reassignment: $(OutputPath)="bin\release/net7.0/linux-x64/" (previous value: "bin\release/net7.0/") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.RuntimeIdentifierInference.targets (280,5)
#25 5.693        The "PublishDir" property is a global property, and cannot be modified.
#25 5.693        The "PublishDir" property is a global property, and cannot be modified.
#25 5.695        Property reassignment: $(_FrameworkIdentifierForImplicitDefine)="NET" (previous value: "NETCOREAPP") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BeforeCommon.targets (181,5)
#25 5.695        Property reassignment: $(_FrameworkVersionForImplicitDefine)="7_0" (previous value: "7.0") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BeforeCommon.targets (186,5)
#25 5.766        Property reassignment: $(CommandLineArgsForDesignTimeEvaluation)="-langversion:11.0 -define:TRACE" (previous value: "-langversion:11.0") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets (188,5)
#25 5.857        The "Configuration" property is a global property, and cannot be modified.
#25 5.859        Property reassignment: $(_DebugSymbolsProduced)="true" (previous value: "false") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (179,5)
#25 5.859        Property reassignment: $(_DocumentationFileProduced)="false" (previous value: "true") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (185,5)
#25 5.864        The "PublishDir" property is a global property, and cannot be modified.
#25 5.864        The "PublishDir" property is a global property, and cannot be modified.
#25 5.864        Property reassignment: $(ClickOncePublishDir)="/source/faas/published/" (previous value: "/source/faas/published") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (497,5)
#25 5.864        Property reassignment: $(ProcessorArchitecture)="amd64" (previous value: "x64") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (516,5)
#25 5.865        Property reassignment: $(DelaySign)="" (previous value: "false") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (568,5)
#25 5.867        Property 'LocalAppData' with value '/root/.local/share' expanded from the environment.
#25 5.869        Property reassignment: $(_SGenGenerateSerializationAssembliesConfig)="Auto" (previous value: "") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (3789,5)
#25 5.870        Property reassignment: $(_TargetsThatPrepareProjectReferences)="
#25 5.870              AssignProjectConfiguration;
#25 5.870              _SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence
#25 5.870            " (previous value: "_SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence") at /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets (4927,5)
#25 5.871        Property 'MSBuildExtensionsPath32' with value '/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.100' expanded from the environment.
#25 5.928 qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
#25 6.319 Segmentation fault
```

If I revert to .NET 6 (both the project and image on Dockerfile) everything works fine.

Comment: Are you on a MacBook with a M1 or M2 chip by chance?

Comment: Doesn't specifically have to be a MacBook. Any Mac that uses an M1 or M2 chip is what I meant.

Comment: @MattThalman yeah, it's a Mac with M1 chip. Should have mentioned that. I'm also passing the `--platform linux/amd64` to the `docker build` command.

Comment: This seems to be related...
https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/27190

Comment: There are two issues. One is the regression between .NET 6 and 7 in terms of the emulation that's happening. The other is that that regression should be avoided by the Docker image you're using. But the problem seems to be that you're getting the amd64 version of the container image instead of the arm64 version. That causes emulation to occur which leads to the regression. There's an active issue that I'm investigating at https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/4225 if you'd like to participate there.

Comment: Thanks @MattThalman. Seems like a regression, as pointed out here https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/4225#issuecomment-1341023873 and here https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/12227

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using `--platform linux/amd64` for your `docker build` command? That's causing emulation to be used and leading to this regression. If you simply omitted the platform option from the build, you would use the arm64 version of the image and it should just work. From within the SDK container, you can still publish an x64 version of the app though.

Comment: Hi @MattThalman, sorry for the late reply. Yeah, the reason is that in this case in particular, I'm building an image intended to run in linux on an M1 chip. It's not usually the case; most projects are using a CI/CD workflow on linux hardware.